# Solaris Imakefile Copy file rule

Tags: c++, solaris, porting

I am trying to port an application from windows to solaris and I found out that the Imakefile is not defined well, or at least is not working at expecting.

I have some rules defined to copy some protobuf files as:

```
file1.pb.cc:
    cp -p $(PROTODIR)/file1.pb.cc .

file2.pb.cc:
    cp -p $(PROTODIR)/file2.pb.cc .

file3.pb.cc:
    cp -p $(PROTODIR)/file3.pb.cc .
```

On windows all the files are copied.

On solaris, only first is copied, then nothing happens.

If I re-run make, I get the message 'file1.pb.cc' is up to date (which is ok, because is there) and the execution is finished.

So, why the other files are not copied ?

Thanks,
Bogdan

Comment: Are you sure you mean Imakefile?   That looks like a normal Makefile.   Imakefiles are used with imake or xmkmf to generate Makefiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a rule at the top of the file:

```
default: file1.pb.cc file2.pb.cc file3.pb.cc
```

The name of the rule is not important, just that it is first. The reason is because `make` will by default only execute the first rule in the file if not given an argument.

This `default` rule then depends on the files you want copied, and `make` will check for rules for them.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E23823_01/html/816-5165/cp-1.html), I don't think you can omit the destination of your copies.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to put the destinations here into the question but on my file I have the correct command line.